# How to tell emacs to separate paragaph by an empty line in quotes

Tags: quote, message-mode

Wit this text:

```
> Play with it a few times you will see my point. The command you need is:
> 
> $ echo hello
```

When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> at the 1st line, I get this

```
> Play with it a few times you will see my point. The
> command you need is: $ echo hello
```

Where what I need is:

```
> Play with it a few times you will see my point. The
> command you need is:
>
> $ echo hello
```

In short, emacs seems not able to tell where the paragraph ends if it is quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for the command `message-fill-yanked-message`, which is bound to `C-c C-q` in `message-mode` by default. See the Message Manual node on [Insertion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/message/Insertion.html) for a brief description of this command, including a caveat.

In fact, `message-mode` is so powerful and flexible that I recommend reading its whole manual, which is relatively short, and/or reading through the user options it provides in `M-x customize-group RET message RET`.

Note that `message-fill-yanked-message` obeys the [buffer-local variable `fill-column`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html) and fills every paragraph in the message. For filling a single paragraph you can use the command `message-fill-paragraph`, which is not bound to any keys by default. When given a [prefix argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html), the latter command also justifies the paragraph.

Comment: `message-fill-yanked-message` is not only *bound* in `message-mode`, it only *exists* in `message-mode`. You get "No Match" if you attempt it in foundation mode.

Comment: @Tankman六四 You seem to be misunderstanding how Emacs modes work. `message-fill-yanked-message` does not exist solely in `message-mode`. The function is defined as soon as `message.el` is loaded, and will continue to exist, i.e. be defined, until you unload the library.

Comment: @Tankman六四 `fundamental-mode` is intended as a bare-bones mode without any features. Specialised editing modes like `text-mode` or `message-mode` depend on the setup that is performed in the eponymous mode function, so their specialised features, such as `message-fill-yanked-message`, will often not work without this setup. It is wrong to assume `message-fill-yanked-message` will work as intended outside of `message-mode` buffers, unless the documentation explicitly says so, or you discover through experimentation otherwise.